# SQL Lock Time out

Tags: java, sql, database

I am not sure if this is a Java or DB problem

```
public boolean addQualification(List<Qualification> qualificationList) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "insert into Qualification(QID,EID, Qualification) values (?,?,?)";
    boolean add = false;
    for (Qualification qualification : qualificationList) {
        Object[] data = {qualification.getQid(), qualification.getEid(),  qualification.getQualification()};
        int result = DBHandle.setData(connection, sql, data);
        if (result > 0) {
            add = true;
        } else {
            add = false;
            connection.rollback();
            break;
        }
    }
    return add;
}
```

When i run this code i got "java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" exception

Comment: Seems the table is locked by some other operation.

Comment: Are you an administrator for the database that you're using? What RDBMS?